# How do you return an exit code from Rhino when embedding it?

Tags: javascript, rhino, embedding, exit-code

I'm using Java to run simple scripts written in JavaScript using the default Rhino bundled by the JRE.  I would like to be able to use the same script within the application and from the command-line version, so I cannot use `java.lang.System.exit(3)` (it would exit the host application prematurely.)  I cannot use the security manager to block it, as people complain about performance issues when a security manager is in effect.

Is there perhaps some function in JavaScript for exiting a script?

Comment: please try to accept answers in more of the questions you've asked, otherwise people may stop posting answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an idea:

Wrap your script in a function and call it. Returning from this function will exit your script.

```
//call main
main();
//The whole work is done in main
function main(){
  if(needToExit){
    //log error and return. It will essentially exit the script
    return;
  }
  //your script goes here
}
```

Comment: This IDEA is quite interesting actually.  It doesn't return an exit code itself, but if you replace "return" with "return 3" then the script as a whole returns "3"... maybe I can get away with introducing a convention where if the script as a whole evaluates to an integer, it is treated as an exit code.  I would have to make this an optional feature because existing scripts might be returning an integer by accident and I don't want them to start failing suddenly after an update.

Answer (score 2):

No, there isn't. But you can create an exception called, say, `ExitError`:

```
public class ExitError extends Error {
    private final int code;

    public ExitError(int code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public int getCode() {
        return code;
    }
}
```

Now, in your application's script runner, you can do this:

```
public int runScript() {
    try {
        // Invoke script via Rhino
    } catch (ExitError exc) {
        return exc.getCode();
    }
}
```

And in the command-line version:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        // Invoke script via Rhino
    } catch (ExitError exc) {
        System.exit(exc.getCode());
    }
}
```

Also, in your JS code, write a wrapper function:

```
function exit(code) {
    throw new ExitError(code);
}
```

Comment: Mmm...that's what I was fearing, but our app doesn't support Rhino so much as it supports JSR223, so I'm trying to find a solution that doesn't involve injecting any JS.

Comment: @Trejkaz: It's very hard to not inject _any_ JS, but here's an example of adding an `exit` function that involves _very_ minimal use of `eval`: http://codepad.org/IDOR4jxY